# How to switch back and forth between Conda and Pyenv without restarting terminal?

Tags: bash, bashrc, anaconda

I'm using both conda and pyenv and would like to switch between both while staying in the same terminal.

The entries to initialize both in my .bashrc look as follows:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/myUser/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/myUser/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/myUser/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/myUser/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

and

```
# Pyenv initialize
export PATH="/home/myUser/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

I simply tried to put the initialization lines (for pyenv) in a separate shell script, however it does not work (pyenv doesn't get initialized).

Info: Pyenv is yet another virtual python environment which I need for usage in combination with poetry

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found at least a work around. It seems that deactivating pyenv once it is activated is a hard thing to do so instead I define a init function in my .bashrc as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348806/deactivate-pyenv-in-current-shell?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
enable-pyenv () {
    # Load pyenv automatically by adding
    # the following to your profile:

    export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
    eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
}
```

Then I simply activate pyenv in every shell on demand. Note that the bash script I tried was not working (probably as it opens a separate shell session).